# why am I getting an error using math.sin(math.pi) in python?

Tags: python

I noticed a glitch while using math.sin(math.pi).
The answer should have been 0 but instead it is 1.2246467991473532e-16.
If the statement is math.sin(math.pi/2) the answer is 1.0 which is correct.
why this error?

Comment: Well it's pretty damn close, isn't it?

Comment: Limited-precision floating-point numbers have limited precision and 0.0000000000000001 is very close to 0.

Comment: math.sin(math.pi)=1.22e-16 but still math.sin(math.pi/2)=1.0
why?

Answer (score 3):

The result is normal: numbers in computers are usually represented with *[floats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point_number)*, which have a finite precision (they are stored in only a few bytes). This means that only a finite number of real numbers can be represented by floats. In particular, π cannot be represented exactly, so `math.pi` is *not* π but a very good approximation of it. This is why `math.sin(math.pi)` does *not* have to be sin(π) but only something very close to it.

The precise value that you observe for `math.sin(math.pi)` is understandable: the relative precision of (double precision) floats is about 1e-16. This means that `math.pi` can be wrong by about π*1e-16 ~ 3e-16. Since sin(π-ε) ~ ε, the value that you obtain with `math.sin(math.pi)` can be in the worst case ~3e-16 (in absolute value), which is the case (this calculation is not supposed to give the exact value but just the correct order of magnitude, and it does).

Now, the fact that `math.sin(math.pi/2) == 1` is not shocking: by the same reasoning as above, `math.pi/2` (a float) is should be at worst at about 2e-16 from the exact value π/2. A Taylor expansion shows that `math.sin(math.pi/2)` should be within 2e-32 from 1: the closest float (with their relative precision of about 1e-16) is therefore 1 (which is exactly represented by floats).

In general, you can expect the result of a function applied to a floating point number to be off by about 1e-16 relative (or be about 1e-16 instead of 0).

Comment: Different implementations of sine in computers can produce different results (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Software_implementations). It may be, though, that it is desirable to have an implementation of sine return 1 for sin(π/2): maybe `math.pi/2` is so close to π/2 that `math.sin(math.pi/2)` should ideally be closer to 1 than to any other float. I reworded the last paragraph so as to make the discussion about sin(π/2) clearer.