# Python3 "math.sin" function returning incorrect result (the angle is in radians.)

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

```
>>> import math
>>> math.sin(math.radians(180))
1.2246467991473532e-16
>>>
```

Isn't the sine of 180º 0.0?

Comment: A more direct duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25615732/270986

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an approximation of pi. You can round it to 0.

Comment: that's a terrible solution. You'll get only 0 or ±1

Comment: You can round it to enough significant digits.